# Advice on generating a sample graph representation (RDF or V-E-V tuples)

Tags: java, python, mapreduce, akka

I want to generate a sample experimental graph data. I would like to be able to specify
number of edges, nodes and graph topology (DAG, polygraph, ...)
There may be a need to generate millions, likely tens of billions of nodes.

In other words, my program should take a number of nodes, number of edges, generate some 
sample distribution which for starters may be purely random and write it out.

Does anyone have a good pointer or a sample code on how to do this with Parallel Python, MapReduce or Akka given the size of the job?

Thank you in advance.